# Why was this question moved to Super User?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, migration

[Is there an open source (read free) tool that allows me to see my browser's HTTP commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1916415/is-there-an-opensource-read-free-tool-that-allows-me-to-see-my-browsers-http-co)

Why would an ordinary (non-programmer) computer user be even remotely interested in this?

Before you say it, I know that programmers also check out Super User. But as someone looking for this kind of information, I would expect it to reside on Stack Overflow, not Super User.

The OP even specifies that the purpose is to observe AJAX interactions, something which a Super User could not care less about.

Comment: The question is opened now.  I doubt anyone will try to close it again, so I'm voting to close this discussion as "No longer relevant"

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with closing or migrating it - understanding protocols is a core skill for programmers(everything is an interface, after all).

I'm voting to open it - it'll remain on both sites once opened again.

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, it was never actually migrated to superuser.com, it was just closed. I'm guessing there wasn't a clear majority in favor of migrating it. Looks like it's re-opened now, though.